# how to run kotlin class file and specify one or more library jar files?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, kotlin, jvm

I am looking for a way to run the standard class file as produced by Intellij for hello world, using a gradle build with `kotlin-stdlib-1.3.11` as the only dependency.

I know I could make a jar file and run that but that is not the question.  That question is already answered in many places,  but please do not answer with those solutions as that is not the question I am asking.

The simple class file for 'hello world' needs access to the kotlin-stdlib-1.3.11.jar, and I am looking for a way to run the class file and manually specify jars to use for satisfying the dependencies.

I am making notes for team members on why:

```
java HelloKt
```

in folder where the class file is located, should give a NoClassDefFoundError and also looking to then show how  manually specifying 'run the class but with the kotlin std lib as well'  should then work.

I repeat, I am not trying to just get the program to run. I am trying to show how run the standard library is required to run the class file.

Answer (score 1):

This is about the [classpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_(Java)).

The easy answer is to run `kotlin` instead of `java`, as that adds the Kotlin support to the classpath automatically:

```
> kotlin HelloKt
```

However, if you need to run `java`, then you'll need to set up the classpath yourself.

The [manpage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/java.html) for `java` says:

> The Java runtime searches for the  startup  class,  and  other  classes used,  in  three  sets  of  locations:  the  bootstrap  class path, the installed extensions, and the user class path.

The first two are part of the Java installation, and rarely touched, so it's the user class path that you need to look at.

You need it to contain both `kotlin-runner.jar` and the path for your `HelloKt.class` file.  The latter could simply be `.` for the current directory; the former will depend where you've installed Kotlin.  (For example, I installed it using Homebrew, and that jar is currently `/usr/local/Cellar/kotlin/1.3.31/libexec/lib/kotlin-runner.jar`.)

The manpage continues:

> ```
>    -classpath classpath
>    -cp classpath
>           Specifies a list of directories, JAR archives, and ZIP  archives
>           to  search for class files.  Class path entries are separated by
>           colons (:). Specifying -classpath or -cp overrides  any  setting
>           of the CLASSPATH environment variable.
>            
>           If -classpath and -cp are not used and CLASSPATH is not set, the
>           user class path consists of the current directory (.).
> ```

So there are two ways you can do this: either set the `$CLASSPATH` environment variable before running `java`:

```
> export CLASSPATH="/usr/local/Cellar/kotlin/1.3.31/libexec/lib/kotlin-runner.jar:."
> java HelloKt
```

Or pass a `-classpath` or `-cp` flag:

```
> java -cp /usr/local/Cellar/kotlin/1.3.31/libexec/lib/kotlin-runner.jar:. HelloKt
```

(Or, as you say, you could build a jar file which includes the Kotlin support classes as well as your own.  That's probably the best option if you're going to distribute it to machines which might not have Kotlin installed.  But it's not the only option.)

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @gidds, yes it is about the classpath.

The command `java HelloKt` is telling java the class to run is `HelloKt`, which is the class Kotlin uses to provide a containing class for an app called `Hello`, but that command does not identify where the code is that should be run.   The code must be specified by the classpath.  With the `HelloKt.class` file in the current directory, then `'.'` as a classpath with allow the HelloKt class to be found and the code to start, but it will quickly die because the repository 'kotlin-stdlib-1.3.11' as specified in the gradle build, must also be available to supply classes for run time. so

```
java -cp ".";"<path to stdlib>\kotlin-stdlib-1.3.11.jar"
```

will successfully run the file.  Note, each jar must be a entry in the classpath, just having the folder containing the jar is not enough.  On windows ';' separates entries, on mac or linux, use ':'.  Each entry can be in quotes, and will need to be only if there are special characters in the path.